# Typescript doesn't generate unreferenced memebers

Tags: javascript, typescript, knockout-mapping-plugin

I've got a problem with JS code generated by TypeScript compiler. 
For a class like this:

```
// Class
export class UserDTO {
    Id: number;
    FirstName: string;
    LastName: string;
    DateOfBirth: Date;

    getFUllName(): string {
        return this.FirstName + ' ' + this.LastName;
    }        
}
```

TypeScript generates the following code:

```
define(["require", "exports"], function(require, exports) {
    // Class
    var UserDTO = (function () {
        function UserDTO() {
        }
        UserDTO.prototype.getFUllName = function () {
            return this.FirstName + ' ' + this.LastName;
        };
        return UserDTO;
    })();
    exports.UserDTO = UserDTO;
});
//@ sourceMappingURL=TestClass.js.map
```

Above code doesn't contains unused (unreferenced) fields but I need them in some 'object-to-object' mapping case'. Is it possible to force compiler to generate them always?

I'm using a TypeScript 0.9.1 from Visual Studio 2012. Here are my compiler options:

```
<TypeScriptTarget>ES5</TypeScriptTarget>
<TypeScriptIncludeComments>true</TypeScriptIncludeComments>
<TypeScriptSourceMap>true</TypeScriptSourceMap>
<TypeScriptModuleKind>AMD</TypeScriptModuleKind>
```

Thanks in advance for any hints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can initialize them when you define them:

```
export class UserDTO {
    Id: number = 0;
    FirstName: string = '';
    LastName: string = '';
    DateOfBirth: Date = undefined;

    getFUllName(): string {
        return this.FirstName + ' ' + this.LastName;
    }        
}
```

Generated javascript:

```
var UserDTO = (function () {
    function UserDTO() {
        this.Id = 0;
        this.FirstName = '';
        this.LastName = '';
        this.DateOfBirth = undefined;
    }
    UserDTO.prototype.getFUllName = function () {
        return this.FirstName + ' ' + this.LastName;
    };
    return UserDTO;
})();
```

[A demo to show looping through such properties.](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/#src=class%20UserDTO%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20Id%3a%20number%20=%200;%0A%20%20%20%20FirstName%3a%20string%20=%20%27%27;%0A%20%20%20%20LastName%3a%20string%20=%20%27%27;%0A%20%20%20%20DateOfBirth%3a%20Date%20=%20undefined;%0A%0A%20%20%20%20getFUllName%28%29%3a%20string%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this.FirstName%20+%20%27%20%27%20+%20this.LastName;%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%09%0A%09logProp%28%29%7B%0A%09%09for%28var%20key%20in%20this%29%7B%0A%09%09%09if%28this.hasOwnProperty%28key%29%29%7B%0A%09%09%09%09console.log%28key%29;%0A%09%09%09%7D%0A%09%09%7D%0A%09%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Avar%20dto%20=%20new%20UserDTO%28%29;%20%0Adto.logProp%28%29;)

Comment: Yes, it's an option - I just assumed that it's possible to auto-initialize them in JavaScript (some compiler switch?). I've checked the code generation specification: http://www.typescriptlang.org/Content/TypeScript%20Language%20Specification.pdf and it seems that only members with assignments are generated. I'll mark your post as an answer if there is no better option.

Comment: i assume that (in Javascript) if you set a member to `null` (e.g. `this.FirstName = null`) that the member will disappear from the object member bag? Which would make it equivalent not referencing them in the first place?

Comment: @IanBoyd False. `null` is a value. Assigning it won't remove a property. `delete obj.property` is how one deletes a property in JavaScript.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to declare fields in JavaScript. TypeScript's field declarations are used for type checking only. You can still access your fields with compiled code as well.

```
var o = new UserDTO();
o.FirstName = 'John';
o.LastName = 'Doe';
console.log(o.getFUllName()); // "John Doe"
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nPr6f/